# MPEG-1 Layer 2 (MP2) decoder-plugin install

Tags: 15.04, codecs

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my machine. When I tried to play a video it asked me to install one plugin (Plugin - MPEG-1 Layer 2 (MP2) decoder). Can anyone help me get this plugin installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can install all codecs, Microsoft fonts and flash in one command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

If you want to install just that codec, run

```
sudo apt-get install libmpeg2-4
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this package:

`apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`

This package contains codecs (or plugins for gstreamer framework rather) that are not particularly well written or stable. It is good enough though.